# Best way to optimize MAPE

Tags: machine-learning, data-transformation, mse, mape

The [MAPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error) is a metric that can be used for regression problems :

$$\mbox{MAPE} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=1}^n  \left|\frac{A_t-F_t}{A_t}\right|$$

Where $A$ represents the actual value and $F$ the the forecast.

I have to optimize my models with respect to this metric. However, I am not sure of the best way to proceed. I could rewrite the objective function of my models (but most of the common libraries do not support custom objective functions) but this requires a lot of efforts.

Alternatively, I could use a transformation $f$ of the target, run the learning on the image $f(target)$ and return the prediction $f^{-1}(predicted)$.

I noticed that training the model, keeping the sum of squares metric, on $\log(target)$ and returning $\exp(predicted)$ resulted in a significant improvement.

Is there a way to know the best transform to use? Or should I cross validate over various transformations of the target?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I noticed that training the model, keeping the sum of squares metric, on log(target) and returning exp(predicted) resulted in a significant improvement.

This does not surprise me. Look at things probabilistically. Your out-of-sample targets follow a certain unknown distribution. You are calculating a point forecast, which is a one-point summary of this unknown distribution, using the expected MAPE as a loss function.

The *first* key question is the following: *which functional of the unknown future distribution minimizes the expected MAPE?* Minimizing the MAPE will automatically draw your predictions to this functional. It turns out that the expected MAPE is minimized by a somewhat exotic functional, the (-1)-median of the future distribution ([Gneiting, 2011, *JASA*](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/jasa.2011.r10138), p. 752 with $\beta = -1$).

However, and this is the *second* key question, I strongly suspect that your *estimation* procedure does not aim at this functional, but uses a loss function that is minimized by the *expected value* of the residuals. This discrepancy between the loss function used by your model estimation algorithm and the loss function you use to evaluate predictions leads to strange results.

[The MAPE tag wiki contains pointers to literature.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/mape/info)

Here is an example. Suppose you have [lognormally distributed data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution), with mean 0 and variance 1 on the log scale, and you have no useful predictors. Without predictors, the fit should be the same for all observations.

- Minimizing the in-sample squared error will lead to a fit which is simply the mean of your data, or $\sqrt{e}\approx 1.65$. A simulation tells us that this fit yields an expected MAPE of about 197% and an expected MSE of about 4.70.
- However, minimizing the MAPE will lead to the (-1)-median of your data, which for the lognormal distribution turns out to be its mode at $\frac{1}{e}\approx 0.37$. The minimal expected MAPE is 68%, while the expected MSE for this fit is 6.34.

The MSE-optimal fit is five times as large as the MAPE-optimal fit, because of the asymmetry of the MAPE - fits that are too large can incur APEs larger than 100%, while the APE is bounded by 100% for fits that are too small. This pulls the MAPE-optimal fit towards zero.

- If you take logarithms of your data and then estimate an MSE-minimizing fit on the logged data, we of course get the mean of the logged data, which is zero. Backtransforming this yields a fit of 1, which is optimal for neither the MAPE nor the MSE for original data, but is closer to the MAPE-optimal value than the original MSE-optimal fit. It yields a MAPE of 113% and an MSE of 5.12.

You probably have asymmetrically distributed data. I would take a *very* critical look at whether the MAPE is really a useful error measure in such a situation. If you do decide to minimize the MAPE, the best solution would quite probably indeed be to change the objective function. If this is not possible, cross-validation and checking various parameters for (say) Box-Cox transformations may be your best bet. (But it would still feel like hammering a nail into a board using a screwdriver instead of a hammer.) In addition, I would very much recommend that you look at your fits' and forecasts' bias and think about whether large biases are a source of concern.

Here is R code for the simulations:

```
set.seed(1)
xx <- rlnorm(1e7)
yy <- sqrt(exp(1))
yy
mean(abs(xx-yy)/xx)
mean((xx-yy)^2)

yy <- 1/exp(1)
yy
mean(abs(xx-yy)/xx)
mean((xx-yy)^2)

yy <- 1
mean(abs(xx-yy)/xx)
mean((xx-yy)^2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answers ! What is the -1-median ? I could not find informations about it...

Comment: That's quite understandable, it's not very common. I have edited my post to include a link to [Gneiting (2011, *JASA*)](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/jasa.2011.r10138). It's discussed on page 752.

Answer (score 1):

Estimating or selecting a model based on its goodness of fit, predictive performance, classification performance, and other fitting-related quantities is not recommended since this strategy tends to over-fit. The best model, based on these criteria, will always be the model with more parameters, since they are always more flexible and, consequently, provide a better fit and better (if little in many cases) predictive performance. The price to pay: using more parameters than you need and getting more spread confidence intervals, and all the unpleasant consequences of over-fitting.

Comment: I am mostly looking at cross validated metrics, so that should help reduce over-fitting.