# Best point forecast for MAPE

Tags: regression, machine-learning, forecasting, loss-functions, mape

I have a data that can have different distribution.

For example every time I get a set of different data :
1, 2, 3, 4. I use metric MAPE and try to find best point to minimize my MAPE. Is there a universal formula that can take my set of data everytime and after that give me best point for prediction for each set of data?

If it would be MSE I would take mean (2,5 for example set) of data for each set, if i would use MAE I would take median of each set but what should I take for each set if I use MAPE ?

Answer (score 0):

[Kolassa gives a reference for the true answer: the (-1)-median of the future distribution.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/213925/247274)

I do not know how to calculate this, so I will turn to a numerical approximation. The following `R` code seems to do the trick.

```
set.seed(2022)
N <- 100
x <- rbinom(10, 100, 1/5) + 1 # Some numbers to try it out

# Function to calculate MAPE
#
mape <- function(y_true, y_pred){
  
  return(
    mean(
      abs(
        (y_true - y_pred)
        /
        (y_true)
      )
    )
  )
}

# Function to find value that minnimizes MAPE for an input x
#
min_mape <- function(x, N = 1000){
  
  x_pred_possibilities <- seq(min(x), max(x), (max(x) - min(x))/(N - 1))
  
  mapes <- rep(NA, length(x_pred_possibilities))
  
  for (i in 1:length(mapes)){
    
    x_preds <- rep(x_pred_possibilities[i], length(x))
    mapes[i] <- mape(x, x_preds)
    
  }
  
  plot(x_pred_possibilities, mapes)
  
  return(x_pred_possibilities[which(mapes == min(mapes))])
  
}

min_mape(x)
```

Without proving that this is the case (indeed, I might be wrong), I speculate that the minimizer of MAPE must not be less than the lowest value and must not be higher than the higher value. The `x_pred_possibilities` variable is all of the numbers between the minimum and maximum values, incrementing up by a fixed amount to give a vector of length `N`, as defined in the function arguments.

Then I make a prediction vector that repeats each `x_pred_possibilities` value so that the prediction is the same for each true value in the input vector `x`. I make every such vector, as allowed by the possibilities in `x_pred_possibilities`. Finally, I graph the MAPE values as a function of the prediction, and I return the prediction value giving the smallest MAPE.

A slight modification allows us to do this for other loss functions, such as MSE or MAE.

```
set.seed(2022)
N <- 100
x <- rbinom(N, 100, 1/5) + 1

# Function to calculate MAPE
#
mape <- function(y_true, y_pred){
  
  return(
    mean(
      abs(
        (y_true - y_pred)
        /
        (y_true)
      )
    )
  )
}

mse <- function(y_true, y_pred){
  return(
    mean(
      (
        y_true - y_pred
      )^2
    )
  )
}

mae <- function(y_true, y_pred){
  return(
    mean(
      abs(
        y_true - y_pred
      )
    )
  )
}

# Function to find value that minnimizes MAPE for an input x
#
min_mape <- function(x, loss, N = 1000){
  
  x_pred_possibilities <- seq(min(x), max(x), (max(x) - min(x))/(N - 1))
  
  mapes <- rep(NA, length(x_pred_possibilities))
  
  for (i in 1:length(mapes)){
    
    x_preds <- rep(x_pred_possibilities[i], length(x))
    mapes[i] <- loss(x, x_preds)
    
  }
  
  plot(x_pred_possibilities, mapes)
  
  return(x_pred_possibilities[which(mapes == min(mapes))])
  
}

min_mape(x, mse, 100000) # 20.90993
mean(x) # 20.91
min_mape(x, mae, 100000) # 21.00009
median(x) # 21
```

My function is highly accurate, being perfect if we round to two decimal places.

[However, note that, despite the initial appeal of MAPE, the metric suffers from some problems, as discussed on its Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error#Issues)

Comment: thank you for numerical solution but i try to find universal analytical. I read Kolassa and did not get how to get -1-median for any distribution. He provided example for log normal. I also did not get -1-median from the article that Kolassa wrote about. That's why I asked here

Comment: @TimurShininov There doesn’t have to be a closed-form solution.